# Dockerhub Create Automated Build step stuck at Creating

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I used this link ([create an Automated Build](https://hub.docker.com/add/automated-build/github/)) from [this guide](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/github/#creating-an-automated-build).

The browser error console shows:

https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/github//autobuild/

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (FORBIDDEN)

Answer (score 7):

I got this hint from https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/411#issuecomment-149878749

I replaced the following URL with my values.

`https://hub.docker.com/add/automated-build/github/form/<GITHUB USER ID>/<GITHUB REPO NAME>/?namespace=<DOCKERHUB NAMESPACE>`

Comment: thanks! This issue was driving me crazy. I guess it happens because I have too many organizations and the page is taking forever to load. I created a simple form in js to create this redirect more easily https://zonca.github.io/docker-auto-build/

Comment: Was really hoping this would work but I just get a 404 from hub.

Answer (score 1):

This workaround has been outdated.
The url returns a 404.
Imho, this has to do with dockerhub changing some policies, concerning 'classic' autobuilds & company/user setup.